# Manually specifying ismorphisms for unidirectional pattern synonym

Tags: haskell, pattern-synonyms

There probably isn't a way to do this, but I just wanted to ask just in case.

I have a data type that's a simple tuple like this:

```
data Tup a = T a a
```

I have a pattern synonym like this:

```
pattern (:?) :: () => Floating a => a -> a -> Tup a
pattern (x :? y) <- T x (sqrt->y)
```

That matches on `T x y`, but gives y square rooted.  so:

```
let (_ :? y) = T 1 4 in y
```

is

```
2.0
```

I'd also like to be able to use `:?` as a constructor, so I'd be able to do cool things like:

```
1 :? 2
```

evaluating to

```
T 1.0 4.0
```

Of course I'd have to manually specify the isomorphism, but is there any syntax or language feature that would enable me to get this behavior?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this particular question, but wanted to mention that you can of course do this with a standard data type like `data Thing = Int :? Int`.  This doesn't help you here though, unless you want to replace the tuple with a data type.

Comment: Yeah, in the actual situation, the tuple is a data type with two fields, if that changes anything :)

Comment: It does, in fact, as per my comment.  Let me write up an answer then.

Comment: Actually, on second thought, the sqrt part is still trouble....  You can do what I suggest, but only to store the actual value, not the sqrt.  Is this something you can also work around?

Comment: @jamshidh would I be storing the actual value, but using a pattern synonym to get the *square* out?  does that change things significantly?

Comment: You could do it with two different inline operators....  Like `??:` to store, `:?` to get out.  That might be confusing though.  When you define an inline constructor, it automatically creates the constructor and pattern, so I doubt using the same thing is possible (and probably not desirable, as people would expect the usual behavior).

Comment: @jamshidh that's what I'm doing right now, but it's a bit unoptimal.  So I was hoping there was a way to be able to merge the two :)  the end goal is that people might be able to only ever work with `:?` as both a constructor and a deconstructor and never worry about `T`

Comment: Looks like @dfeuer found a better soln....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of GHC 7.10, you can use

```
pattern (:?) :: () => Floating a => a -> a -> Tup a
pattern (x :? y) <- T x (sqrt->y) where
  x :? y = T x (y^2)
```

My main concern is that `sqrt` and `^2` are not quite inverses, both because negative numbers don't have real square roots and because floating point arithmetic is imprecise.

Comment: oh, that's nice!  I wonder if I'm just really bad at looking at the documentation?

Comment: as for the imperfect isomorphism, one of the internally maintained constraints of the `Tup` type is that it never stores any negative numbers, so this invariance is internally maintained by the library.  The user is never allowed to directly create values types with the `T` constructor, so exporting only `+/-` makes things work nicely.  thanks!